# parameter cc_lang_pref does not work in 2024?

Tags: javascript, php, embed

Does the cc_lang_pref and cc_load_policy parameters not work in 2024? I'm trying to include them in my code, but they don't seem to work. It only works when I set h1=es, but sometimes it gets stuck in the same language. In incognito mode, it can switch to other languages, but the primary language doesn't work. In normal mode, only the primary language works, and the others don't work.

```
var iframeCode = `<iframe height="500" src="${videoUrl}?origin=https://plyr.io&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;hl=es" allowfullscreen allowtransparency allow="autoplay"></iframe>`;
```

..
..
..
..
..
..
..
..

Comment: To embed a YouTube video?

Comment: yes, is a embed youtube

Comment: Those parameters seem to be [supported](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters). Is it possible to create an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here to help demonstrate the issue?